# Clicking a button to change views in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When a user accesses my page they are taken to a home screen (which currently has a title and 1 button).  The one button is start game which should redirect to a view that has the game board on it.  How do I send that information from the button to the controller to access a new view.
This is the button that is in my view (the button should send the information to function click() )

```
<form id="start" action="index.php/click" method="POST" >
            <input type="submit" name="start" value="startGame" />
</form>
```

Now in the controller index.php

```
function click()
    {
        $action = $_POST['submit'];
        if($action == 'startGame')
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }
    }
```

I have it loading the welcome_message just for sakes to learn how to redirect.  (My group hasn't fully build the game board page)

Answer (score 8):

There are couple of things you need to change. 
1. Try to use another name instead of `"index.php"` for controller. For example `"test.php"`. I think index.php is not allowed for controller name.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function click()
    {
        $action = $this->input->post('start'); // $_POST['start']; also works. 
        if($action == 'startGame')
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        }
    }
}
```

2.Change the value of `action` as follows in your view.

```
<form id="start" action="test/click" method="POST" >
   <input type="submit" name="start" value="startGame" />
</form>
```

This should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
function click()
{
    $action = $_POST['start'];
    if($action == 'startGame')
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```